# Installation of Joomla extension make apache core dump

Tags: apache, joomla

I installed joomla 3.2 on my ubunut 12 server and try to install some extension on it 
But every time I have a failure of "No data received" in chrome

I checked apache log and I found following log:

> [Thu Mar 06 01:06:08 2014] [notice] child pid 4278 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
>
> 192.168.2.119 - - [06/Mar/2014:01:05:40 +0100] "GET /acece/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=update&task=update.ajax&eid=0&skip=700
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 293  "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"

Any one have some idea?

The same server ran joomla 2.5 before without any problem

I tried to update the packages of ubuntu , but nothing changes

Comment: Are you sure your extension supports Joomla 3.2?

Comment: Yes , as I try to install joomla extensions directory -- the official extension market of joomla. Even this won't work

Comment: Try to install a clean Joomla, do you have the same behavior? Perhaps it helps to increase the log level in apache https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel.